# Proving a piecewise function has an inverse.

Tags: functions, elementary-set-theory, inverse-function

I am trying to prove the following:

> Let $A$, $B$, $C$, and $D $ be sets. Let $ g:A\to C $ and let $h:B\to D$. Then, we can define a function $$\phi(x)=\begin{cases}
> g(x),  &        \text{if } x\in A \\
> h(x), &         \text{if } x\in B
> \end{cases}$$
>    Then if $g$ is a bijection from $ A $ to $ C$, and $h$ is a bijection from $ B $ to $ D$, $A\cap B = \emptyset$, and $ C\cap D = \emptyset$, then $ \phi $ is a bijection from $ X $ to $ Y $, and for all $ y \in Y $ we have $$ \phi ^{-1}(y)=\begin{cases}
> g^{-1}(y),  &   \text{if } y\in C \\
> h^{-1}(y), &    \text{if } y\in D
> \end{cases}$$

I am mainly stuck on showing that $\phi$ has an inverse. Any help is appreciated!

Comment: I think there need to be $A\cap B=\emptyset$, too. right?

Comment: yes, ill edit the question

Comment: Argh! **Don't** use math mode for prose text! Why do people do that? It must have taken a lot of tedious typing work to write that horrible abuse of MathJax -- why why why?

Comment: it did take a lot of work lol

Answer (score 1):

You don't need to show in a vacuum that $\phi$ has an inverse -- since the problem *explicitly tells you* what the inverse will be, you can simply go ahead and *define*
$$ \psi(y)=\begin{cases}
g^{-1}(y),  &   \text{if } y\in C \\
h^{-1}(y), &    \text{if } y\in D
\end{cases}$$
and then show directly element for element that $\psi$ satisfies the condition of being an inverse of $\phi$.

Once you have shown that $\phi$ has an inverse, this will tell you for free that it is a bijection.

Comment: I thought we were assuming all the things about $\phi $, g, and h and proving that $\phi $ is bijective AND $\phi $ has an inverse as defined by that piecewise function.

Comment: @kanker7: Yes -- how does that contradict what I'm writing? The most fundamental way to prove that $\phi$ _has_ an inverse is to _show that inverse explicitly_.

Comment: But how can we do that if we're simply defining the the inverse of $\phi $? Wouldn't we be trying to prove what we've just assumed?

Comment: @kanker7: I don't understand what your problem is. What you want to prove is that there exists a function that has the property of being an inverse of $\phi$. The problem helpfully tells you what that function is, so the only thing left for _you_ to prove is that the function the problem defined does indeed have the property of being an inverse of $\phi$.